# Tabulator tables context click event needed before editor

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm relatively conversant with Tabulator, however a client has asked me to when right clicking on a cell to bring up a menu, and when left clicking a cell to edit.
I'm having trouble grabbing a left or right mouse event before the editor kicks in.

I've read what I assumed to be the right technique here: https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/1242
But it seems the 'contextClick' event no longer exists.

Instead in the docs, the following events exist, and I can't get any of them to fire before the editor, custom or "number", in the code below:

```js
{
    columns:[
        {title:"u2",        field:"u2",         editor:"number",    editable:true},
    ],
    cellClick:function(e, cell){    
        console.log('cell left');
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    },
    cellContext:function(e, cell){
        console.log('cell right');
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    },
    rowContext:function(e, cell){
        console.log('row right');
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    },
    contextClick:function(e, cell){
        console.log('context click');
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    },
}
```

On right click, the output is 'cell right' but the editor, either "number" or a custom editor fires beforehand.
I confirmed there is no difference with a custom editor, the custom editor being triggered before 'cell right' is logged.

Answer (score 0):

The context click causing edits was a bug that has been resolved in the 4.8 release of Tabulator.

Tabulator does also come with its own built in context menu functionality if you would prefer a simpler setup.

You can setup context menus by using the ***contextMenu*** option in the column definition:

```js
//define row context menu
var cellContextMenu = [
    {
        label:"Reset Value",
        action:function(e, cell){
            cell.setValue("");
        }
    },
]

//add header menu in column definition
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"name", width:200, contextMenu:cellContextMenu}, //add a context menu to the cells in this column
    ]
});
```

Checkout the [Menu Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/menu) for further details